# Windows 8.1 Program switches to desktop

Tags: windows-8, desktop, switch, windows-8.1

I've got some weird issue happening since I installed Windows 8.1 when it officially came out.

Every day, approximately within 10 minutes after boot of the system, the program (in all cases so far Mozilla Firefox) will switch by itself from window-filled mode to the desktop, so all I see is the desktop.

Then when I click on the icon again in the taskbar, it pops up again, but now snapped to the left (WIN key + Left key). Then I restore it again to window-filled mode.

I have absolutely no clue what is happening.

Comment: "all I see is the desktop"... by that you mean, like, your wallpaper and your taskbar only? Just making sure... you're not doing something like putting your mouse in the lower left corner which hides the desktop, right? But uhm, if I were you I'd try to reinstall Firefox, especially if it was already there on Windows 8 and it was carried over to 8.1. There's a chance something went wrong in keeping the program throughout the upgrade.

Comment: @Ariane Yeah wallpaper, icons and taskbar is what I meant. I'll try reinstalling Firefox then, it luckily isn't really annoying so not worth reinstalling W8.1 over